# Can VSCode create callback method scaffolding for TypeScript automatically?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

In VS + C#, when I type `+=` to an event, the event handler method scaffolding is automatically created with the correct argument/return types. With TypeScript, can VS Code do a similar thing?

For example, in the following code

```
import * as http from 'http';

http.createServer
```

VS Code shows the type of the callback in the pop-up, and if I press F12 to jump to the definitions, it has all the information about the callback types. But if I type `onReq` and choose "Ctrl+.:Add missing method declaration", it inserts the following

```
function onReq(onReq: any)
{
  throw new Error('Function not implemented.');
}
```

This is useless. Can't it add something like the following?

```
function onReq(req: http.IncomingMessage, res: http.ServerResponse)
{
  throw new Error('Function not implemented.');
}
```

Did I do something wrong, or VS Code can't insert the correct scaffolding even though it knows all the information?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## IDE != Code Editor

Let's begin by understand the difference between IDE and code editor. once we know the difference we can improve how vscode infers yow code.

You can add your own snippets.

### Snippets

There is something even better at the root of your project add a new dir call `.vscode`

So you'll have some like

```
.vscode
node_modules
public
src
```

in the new dir add a file call `whatever-name-you-want.code-snippets` for example `react.code-snippets`.

```
.vscode
 - react.code-snippets
node_modules
public
src
```

Open the new file and paste this

```json
{
    // Place your workspace snippets here. Each snippet is defined under a snippet name and has a scope, prefix, body and 
    // description. Add comma separated ids of the languages where the snippet is applicable in the scope field. If scope 
    // is left empty or omitted, the snippet gets applied to all languages. The prefix is what is 
    // used to trigger the snippet and the body will be expanded and inserted. Possible variables are: 
    // $1, $2 for tab stops, $0 for the final cursor position, and ${1:label}, ${2:another} for placeholders. 
    // Placeholders with the same ids are connected.
    // Example:
    "Print to console": {
        "prefix": "log",
        "body": [
            "console.log('$1');",
            "$2"
        ],
        "description": "Log output to console"
     },
     "onReq": {
        "prefix": "onreq",
        "body": [
            "function onReq(req: http.IncomingMessage, res: http.ServerResponse) {",
            "\tthrow new Error('Function not implemented.');",
            "}"
        ],
     }

}
```

you can add all the ones you prefer.

### DefinitelyTyped

The typescript community has a huge community and there are some libraries already typed for you

#### Packages

You can find the available packages here https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types